# Book to read after Bishop's "Pattern..." to complete my stats knowledge

Tags: probability, self-study, mathematical-statistics, references

I am finishing the (very good, although demanding) "Pattern recognition and machine learning". I think I have learnt a lot. My previous knowledge in statistics and probability was very superficial. I would like to know more about statistics and probability, trying to cover the topics that Bishop doen't treat in his great book.

So I suppose this question is mostly for people who know Bishop's "Pattern...", but I invite everybody to answer. Bishop's book is very strong in the machine learning part, but, for example, the part of the statistical tests (in a frequentist or Bayesian approach) is missing, as far as I have noticed.

Some time ago, not related to this question, I was recommended the book "Probability theory, the logic of science", by E. T. Jaynes. (I am a physicist, so I suppose this is a book that attracts me naturally). Is it a good option to continue learning about prob and stats? Do you know other options?

Thank you very much.

Comment: *Complete* your stats knowledge? A long shelf of books couldn't do that.  If you want to really get started learning stats, I'd start with Kendall and Stuart Vol 1 (who is it by now? Stuart and Ord I think), but - while reasonably comprehensive for what it talks about (mostly distribution theory, and the mathematical tools required are pretty basic -- no measure theory is required for example) - even that has no coverage of the many important topics outside its scope.  If you narrow things down a bit, maybe something more useful to you could be said.

Comment: @Glen_b Stuart and Ord 1994 remains the latest edition of that volume.

Comment: @Glen_b ok, thanks, I suppose what I wanted to say is that I want to _continue_ learning statistics. I am mostly interested in the Bayesian paradigm, perhaps because I am biased because of my readings, but it is also true that it is what attracts me more.